# GTM indicating GA tag is "still running"

Tags: google-tag-manager

A GA tag fired upon the purchase event bears that status "still running". 
In the network I see:
A collect statement indicating data has been sent to GA
eCommerce parameters aren't included (thus omitted)
Data isn't being captured in GA
Only source of info on the "still running" issue I've found was this:
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-tag-in-gtm-still-running/

However, this is not the issue.
Any ideas on root causes that might trigger this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I had the same issue when the lookup table that was feeding the UA identifier on my Analytics variable was broken, do you have a similar setup? If not, could you share some information about your setup?

Comment: Currently I'm trying to inject Enhanced eCommerce Purchase event through GTM. The script runs on the TY page (HubSpot iFrame) & launches the event:purchase command followed by the purchase code. I've configured a GA Transaction tag to use event:purchase as a trigger. But it stays 'idle' as it semmes to be unable to complete firing the tag.

Comment: Unfortunately without more information about the exact configuration of your tag, trigger and analytics variable I cannot help you troubleshoot further, this error might be caused by many factors, usually it's because something is wrong with your UA variable.

Comment: Simon, the king of analytics has spoken. https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/still-running-google-tag-manager-tags/ I know, 11 months later - but maybe you still have this problem :)